# count the number of occurrences in a files for particular column using awk

Tags: linux, file, unix, awk, count

I have one file which has the below input

```
1,1_2_34_45.csv,2345
2,1_2_34_45.csv,2345
3,1_2_34_45.csv,2345
4,1_2_34_46.csv,2346
5,1_2_34_47.csv,2345
```

for that i need the following out put below

```
1_2_34_45.csv,2345,3
1_2_34_46.csv,2346,1
1_2_34_47.csv,2345,1
```

I have tried the below code

```
 awk -F , '{a[$2]++ }END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' table.txt > count.txt
```

but it prints only count,$2 value but the other column details doesnt show up as desired output please help me

Comment: No that . might have come up from my typing as I'm doing it through mobile

Comment: and what would the output look like if there were multiple $3 values for a given $2?

Comment: No $3 would be same input as it's the total countof that CSV value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the values you want in the array key might be sufficient.

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$2 FS $3]++} END {for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' OFS=, input.txt
1_2_34_47.csv,2345,1
1_2_34_46.csv,2346,1
1_2_34_45.csv,2345,3
```

Note that with an awk script this simple, the output order cannot be guaranteed. (That is, array order is not guaranteed.)  If you want to control the order, you'd be best to use an additional array:

```
$ awk -F, '{k=$2 FS $3} !a[k]++{o[i++]=k} END {for(j=0;j<i;j++){print o[j],a[o[j]]}}' OFS=, input.txt
1_2_34_45.csv,2345,3
1_2_34_46.csv,2346,1
1_2_34_47.csv,2345,1
```

The second array has an incrementing key that we can step through using a for loop as a counter. The counter preserves the original order of "new" keys in the input stream.

Comment: could you please explain me the !a[k] scenario

Comment: FWIW I'd preserve the order by printing when $2 changes rather than waiting til the END. Looks like the inputs sorted on $2 and if not it's easy to do before calling awk.

Comment: @narman12, `!a[k]++` is a *condition*. A variable, or array member with a value of 0 evaluates as false. The `++` increments the value, but not before it has been accessed for use in the condition, and the `!` negates the logic. So, this condition (1) is true if that array member is unset or `0`, and (2) increments the value after it is evaluated.

Comment: @EdMorton, I don't disagree, and doing it as you suggest would eliminate the memory footprint of the array. But you'd still need code in END - perhaps a call to a function - to handle the count of the last key. It starts to grow into more than a one-liner. :-) I'll add something like this if the OP mentions memory problems or very large input files, or is running this on a stream that never ends (like a `tail -f`).

Comment: Right, I always write a prt() function to be called at the transition and from the END.

Comment: @ghoti if there are three variables in the input then [$2 FS $3 FS $4] would suffice or do we need to do something more on counting

Comment: @narman12, sure, you can include whatever fields define a record as unique in your array key. You can even include functions or arithmetic evaluations if that's helpful.

Comment: i have a record like below                                                           1_2_3_45.csv|4|Not Found;
1_2_3_45.csv|4|Not Found;
1_2_3_45.csv|4|Found;
1_2_3_45.csv|4|Found ;                                                                                        then my output is like                                                                                             
12345|1_2_3_45.csv|4|4|NotFound;
12345|1_2_3_45.csv|4|4|Found;
where in my desired output is 12345|1_2_3_45.csv|4|2|Found/Not Found; could you help me on that @ghoti

Comment: Comments are terrible with formatting, especially when your backquote key is broken. It's hard for me to tell what your input really looks like. If this new information clarifies your question, please edit your question and add it as an update. Or, if it's a new requirement or you're still stuck after implementing what you got out of *this* question, perhaps a new question is in order! :)